# Set alignment of ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, alignment, android-imageview, android-tablelayout

I created a table with five table rows. The first row is the header of each table.
In the following four rows each second column shell represent an image and a textview.
My problem is that my image is displayed in the center of the row.
If I add some layoutparams to the image for their width, it disappears.

I want that the alignment of my picture is left, so its right next to my first column ends.

[image] [image]

Creating the rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
    for (int column = 1; column <= 8; column++) {
        TextView textView = null;
        if (column == 2) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableRow.addView(imgView);
            textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setGravity(LEFT);
        } else {
            textView = new TextView(context);
        }

        textView.setGravity(CENTER);
        textView.setTextColor(WHITE);
        tableRow.addView(textView);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
```

Update the table with data:

```
for (int column = 0; column <= 7; column++) {
    View child = tableRow.getChildAt(column);
    if (child instanceof ImageView) {
        ImageView flag = (ImageView) child;
        flag.setImageResource(getFlagByClubName(group.getTeams().get(i).getClub()));
    }
    if (child instanceof TextView) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(column);
        setContentInColumn(group.getTeams().get(i), column, textView);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what? The ImageView is just to bit. The image in the ImageView is displayed in the center but the view itself is too big. If i set the width via LayoutParams on the ImageView, my Image isnt shown anymore

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to set the width please?

Comment: I did that. I just added WRAP_CONTENT to the layout params, but then i dont see my image anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You could try wrapping the imageview and textview in a relative layout. Please note I haven't tested the code below, but it's adapted from some other code of mine that works fine.

```
    RelativeLayout wrapper = new RelativeLayout(context);

    // Create imageView params
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams;
    imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    // Create imageView
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
    imageView.setId(1);

    // Create textView params
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams;
    textParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, imageView.getId());

    // Create textView
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setLayoutParams(textParams);

    // Add to the wrapper
    wrapper.addView(imageView);
    wrapper.addView(textView);
```

And then just add `wrapper` to your table:

```
tableRow.addView(wrapper);
```

Comment: When i use that, the image and the textview of that RelativeLayout are just gone. They must be hidden from anything else...